# Частичное обновление на ajax: модифицировать рабочий вариант

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте.
На движке modx revo есть дополнение фильтрации материалов. Работает оно на ajax: обновление блока с самими фильтрами, обновление контент части и пагинации. Кнопки тоже есть, но по сути не используются.

Вот [js скрипт](https://minishop2.com/assets/components/msearch2/js/web/default.js?v=1.71) (ссылка потому что сюда не влезает).
id обёртки с фильтрами: mse2_mfilter
id формы с фильтрами: mse2_filters
id обёртки контента: mse2_results
id обертки пагинации: mse2_pagination

К сожалению ко всему этому предоставить html разметку не представляется возможным.

**Задача:** при выборе какого-то фильтра, автоматически должен обновляться только блок с фильтрами. Блок контента и пагинация необходимо обновлять только при нажатии submit'а в форме фильтров.